# Why destruct is being called here explicitly?

Tags: c++11, c++-cli, destructor

While browsing some code related to sending E-mail through SMTP, I got following snippet in MSDN.

```
static void CreateMessageWithAttachment( String^ server )
{
   String^ file = L"data.xls";

   MailMessage^ message = gcnew MailMessage( L"jane@contoso.com",L"ben@contoso.com",L"Quarterly data report.",L"See the attached spreadsheet." );

   Attachment^ data = gcnew Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames::Application::Octet);

   ContentDisposition^ disposition = data->ContentDisposition;
   disposition->CreationDate = System::IO::File::GetCreationTime( file );
   disposition->ModificationDate = System::IO::File::GetLastWriteTime( file );
   disposition->ReadDate = System::IO::File::GetLastAccessTime( file );

   message->Attachments->Add( data );

   SmtpClient^ client = gcnew SmtpClient( server );

   client->Credentials = CredentialCache::DefaultNetworkCredentials;
   client->Send( message );

   data->~Attachment();
   client->~SmtpClient();
}
```

I am just wondering why they are calling destructor here? am I missing something here?

```
 data->~Attachment();
 client->~SmtpClient();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++/CLI, a `ref` class destructor is an abstraction over the [*Dispose* pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx).

The following C++/CLI class, when compiled:

```cpp
public ref class Test
{
public:
    Test() { System::Console::WriteLine("ctor"); }
    ~Test() { System::Console::WriteLine("dtor"); }

    static void Foo()
    {
        auto foo = gcnew Test();
        foo->~Test();
    }
};
```

Decompiles to the following C# code (C# semantics are much closer to the underlying IL code so it's a good way to visualize what happens):

```cs
public class Test : IDisposable
{
    public Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ctor");
    }

    private void ~Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dtor");
    }

    public static void Foo()
    {
        new Test().Dispose();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] bool A_0)
    {
        if (A_0)
        {
            this.~Test();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Finalize();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize((object)this);
    }
}
```

You can see the dispose pattern is implemented automatically by the compiler.

The `~Test` "destructor" is compiled to a private method, and an implementation of `IDisposable::Dispose` is generated for you. The compiler also calls the (empty) finalizer for some reason.

Also, as you can see in the static `Foo` method, `foo->~Test();` is simply translated to a call to `Dispose`. The compiler won't let you call `foo->Dispose();` directly.

But the *standard* approach to call the "destructor" (and therefore the `Dispose` method) is to use the `delete` keyword: `delete foo;` is the same as `foo->~Test();` in C++/CLI when `foo` is a managed handle.

Note that in this example, instead of writing:

```cpp
auto foo = gcnew CppCli::Test();
foo->Whatever();
delete foo;
```

You could use stack semantics and write:

```cpp
Test foo;
foo.Whatever();
```

`foo.~Test();` will be called when `foo` goes out of scope, like in regular C++.

---

For completeness, here's how the whole thing interacts with finalizers. Let's add one:

```cpp
public ref class Test
{
public:
    Test() { System::Console::WriteLine("ctor"); }
    ~Test() { System::Console::WriteLine("dtor"); }
    !Test() { System::Console::WriteLine("finalizer"); }
};
```

This decompiles to the following C#-like code:

```cs
public class Test : IDisposable
{
    public Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ctor");
    }

    // This is the real finalizer
    ~Test()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    // This is what C++/CLI compiles ~Test to
    // Let's call this MethodA
    private void ~Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dtor");
    }

    // This is what C++/CLI compiles !Test to
    // Let's call this MethodB
    private void !Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finalizer");
    }

    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    protected virtual void Dispose([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] bool A_0)
    {
        if (A_0)
        {
            this.~Test(); // MethodA, NOT the finalizer
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                this.!Test(); // MethodB
            }
            finally
            {
                base.Finalize();
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize((object)this);
    }
}
```

Note that, for added confusion, in C# the finalizer is `~Test()`, which is *different* from the `private void ~Test()` function that the C++/CLI compiler generates for your destructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation, Really helpful.

Comment: You should probably also note that the `~Test()` syntax is not standard. The canonical way to dispose a managed object is to use `delete`, same as one would a C++ object.

Comment: @DavidYaw oops, you're right, that's an important point, thanks!

Comment: @DavidYaw yes that would be definitely less confusing :)